# c# winform dwfx image streamed into a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, viewer

I have googled this quite a bit and I can't find any references. Is it possible to stream a raw dwfx or to parse/ convert and import dwfx files into a listview as item images?

Comment: Did you even try to google for *"dwfx c#"*? The first [result](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=5801732) seems good, no?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best option, but since DWFX is practically XPS, you can try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560041/how-to-convert-a-xps-file-to-an-image-in-high-quality-rather-than-blurry-low-re) method to convert the file to jpeg, then simply add them to the list view