# Exporting eps from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, export, distortion

I am trying to produce high quality EPS files (1000 dpi) for an Elsevier journal.  I have been using export_fig, but when I try to view the files, they are squished and distorted.  Does anyone know to produce an eps that looks the same as the figure on the screen?

Comment: there was already some discussion on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788168/matlab-export-plot-to-vector-format), you might find some of it useful

Comment: yeah, I am using export_fig, it seems that the problem is the painters renderer.  I want to use it to keep my lines looking nice, butit changes the font size.  Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

When I was exporting eps figures I had a lot of success using 
[Oliver Woodford's](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29192) function [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) found on mathworks file exchange.

He has updated it since I used it, but it's probably only gotten better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of steps that I follow for my publications that has never failed me so far. I am including all the steps which might be more that what you are asking for. Here it is

1.Plot with the correct linewidth and/or marker size

2.Set font size

3.Set X and Y lims

4.Set X and Y ticks

5.Set X and Y tick labels if appropriate

6.Set X and Y axis labels

7.Set units of the figure to inches

8.Set the size of the figure

9.Export using export_fig with the -painters option

```
hf = figure();
plot(x,y,'Linewidth',1);
set(gca,'FontSize',8);
xlim([a,b]);
ylim([c,d]);
set(gca,'XTick',a:ab:b);
set(gca,'YTick',c:cd:d);
xlabel('Xlabel');
ylabel('Ylabel');
set(gcf,'units','inches');
set(gcf,'Position',[0 0 fig_width fig_height]);
export_fig(filename,'-transparent','-eps','-painters');
```

The final `-painters` is important since sometimes dashed and dot-dash linstyles don't get exported correctly. The same method works with -pdf too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hgexport.

```
x = 0:.1:pi;
h = figure();
plot(x, sin(x));
hgexport(h, 'sin.eps');
```

UPDATE
print and saveas also work.