# Invalid property 'PickableParts' using line in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using the following script:

http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48576-circulargraph

to create an schemaball from a correlation matrix (my related earlier question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038377/how-to-visualize-correlation-matrix-as-a-schemaball-in-matlab/17284017)). When I try to run the script (e.g. example.m file) I get the following error (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image]

I'm using Matlab R2014a. What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Well, it says [here](https://github.com/paul-kassebaum-mathworks/circularGraph) that Matlab 2014b is required, and there is a [big difference in graphics between this versions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html). So I guess it won't be a simple task...

Comment: Okay, shame. Then I won't be able to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EBH already mentioned it seems I can't use this script on Matlab R2014a.